# Missing new line after PHP block

Tags: php

When I processed the following file `src.php`:

```
<?php
include "params.php";
?>
Str 1
val a = <?=$b?>
Str 3
```

where the `params.php` file:

```
$b = 123;
```

`$ php src.php > tgt.txt`

I get the result:

```
Str 1
val a = 123Str 3
```

instead of

```
Str 1
val a = 123
Str 3
```

How shoud I solve this problem? Should I add an additional line break after `<?=b?>` through all my code?

Comment: Better add `;` at the end of line to avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue I've come across before with the way PHP blocks are processed, the first line-break after `?>` is, as far as I know, always ignored.  This is probably[citation needed] to avoid problems when using 'code only' PHP files which would output a trailing newline when `include`'d, e.g.:

```
-- some_file.php
<?php
// some class/function definitions, etc.
?>
+ trailing newline

-- some_other_file.php
include 'some_file.php'; // this would actually output a linebreak
```

As a lot of UNIX editors enjoy messing around with your whitespace this was probably seen as a necessary '[feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undocumented_feature)' in order to avoid this issue.

**TL;DR:**

The only workaround I'm aware of is to either concatenate a linebreak to your output

```
<?= $b.PHP_EOL ?>
```

or add another linebreak in the HTML

```
val a = <?= $b ?>

Str 3
```

Both of these solutions suck, but I don't know any other way around.

**EDIT:** A different approach would be to use heredoc strings:

```
echo <<<STUFF
Str 1
val a = $b
Str 3
STUFF;
// must be a break after `STUFF;`
```

That way formatting is still clear, and it behaves as you'd expect it (though a caveat with heredocs is there must be a linebreak after the terminating `STUFF;`, or you'll get a parse error, at least on 5.4).

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE thanks to adam:

try

```
$b = "123".PHP_EOL;
```

anyway seems like you need to add a new line :)

Comment: Consider using the constant `PHP_EOL` instead, as it provides an OS-specific newline

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:

```
val a = <?=$b."\n";?>
Str 3
```

Or just:

```
val a = <?=$b;?><br/>
Str 3
```